# Json.Net TypeNameHandling.Auto and Asp Web Api Controller gives unexpected behaviour

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

Assume `TypeNameHandling.Auto` is used for Json.net in the following Web Api Controllers:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

class FooController : ApiController
{
  public A Get() {
    return new A();
  }
}

class BarController : ApiController
{
  public A Get() {
    return new B();
  }
}
```

Then I would expect the resulting Json to be:

**Foo**

```
{}
```

**Bar**

```
{'$type':...}
```

However, the output of Bar is also `{}`. On the other hand, if the API controller returned `IEnumerable<A>` and we returned a lot of `B`'s then the type property is set.

Is it possible to change this behaviour such that it uses the return type as input to Json.Net?

A fix is to return the Json and not the object but I find that a dissatisfactory solution.

Comment: It appears that in general json.net works this way...you can take a look at this issue was closed actually, but take a note of the last 2 comments: http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23891

Comment: No, I can easily make it work by invoking `JsonConvert` myself. It is possible to provide `Serialize` with a type argument. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, typeof(T), Formatting.None, null)`

Comment: @KiranChalla I'm not sure I follow you. In my example, the return type could be changed to `object` while still generating the exact same Json. But that is not the case for the types of members or the element types in `IEnumerable<T>`. Personally, I believe the return type should be treated the same way as members of the return type. Do you consider manually serialising the return object the best solution with the correct semantics?

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. I just now tried a standalone console app having Json.net and tried your scenario and noticed that Json.net provides an overload on `JsonSerializer` which accepts the type of the object `public void Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, object value, Type objectType);`...Currently Web API does not use this overload, but uses the one not taking in the type...looks like this should be added into the formatter...for your scenario to work as you expect, I think creating a custom json formatter would be an option...i will try to get an example regarding this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for this scenario as I think this is something which should be included by default in our Json formatter. Following is a custom Json formatter where I try to pass in the 'type' information to the `Serialize` method of `JsonSerializer`. I tried the below custom formatter with your scenario and it seemed to work fine.

(Most of the code below was cherry picked from existing Web API source code to suit your scenario.)

```
public class CustomJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        try
        {
            Encoding effectiveEncoding = SelectCharacterEncoding(content == null ? null : content.Headers);

            if (!UseDataContractJsonSerializer)
            {
                using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(writeStream, effectiveEncoding)) { CloseOutput = false })
                {
                    if (Indent)
                    {
                        jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
                    }

                    JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(this.SerializerSettings);
                    jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, value, type); //NOTE: passing in 'type' here
                    jsonTextWriter.Flush();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, writeStream, content, transportContext);
            }

            return TaskHelpers.Completed();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return TaskHelpers.FromError(e);
        }
    }
}

internal class TaskHelpers
{
    private static readonly Task _defaultCompleted = FromResult<AsyncVoid>(default(AsyncVoid));

    /// <summary>
    /// Used as the T in a "conversion" of a Task into a Task{T}
    /// </summary>
    private struct AsyncVoid
    {
    }

    internal static Task<TResult> FromResult<TResult>(TResult result)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        tcs.SetResult(result);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an error task. The task is Completed, IsCanceled = False, IsFaulted = True
    /// </summary>
    internal static Task FromError(Exception exception)
    {
        return FromError<AsyncVoid>(exception);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an error task of the given type. The task is Completed, IsCanceled = False, IsFaulted = True
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    internal static Task<TResult> FromError<TResult>(Exception exception)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        tcs.SetException(exception);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a completed task that has no result. 
    /// </summary>        
    internal static Task Completed()
    {
        return _defaultCompleted;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you :-) In case MS(you) want to make it the default behaviour it might also make sense to make the change for `Json.Encode` in web helpers.

Comment: I added a few extra lines to the solution (see my answer) because this solution gave unexpected results for arrays and other special types.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. However, after I plugged in your custom formatter, I don't see it making any difference. In fact, WriteToStreamAsnc doesn't get hit at all. What might be wrong? This is my code in WebApiConfig.cs: `config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(new CustomJsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto } });`

Answer (score 0):

I had to change Kiran's solution with the following such that arrays etc. will be written as `[...]` instead of `{$type: IEnumerab...., values = ...}`.

```
var contract = jsonSerializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(type);

// Only use the declared type if it is an object contract such that
// arrays, dictionaries, etc. aren't affected.
if (contract is JsonObjectContract)
{
    jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, value, type); // NOTE: passing in 'type' here
}
else
{
    jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, value);
}
```