# How to pass abstract class to Asp.Net WebApi using Json formatter?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Basically, I'm trying to make my WebApi more generic:

Model:

```
public abstract class A {}
public class B : A { }
```

Client:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49611/");  
    var aList = List<A> { new B() };
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/a", aList);
}
```

WebApi controller:

```
public class AController : ApiController
{
    public void Post([FromBody]List<A> aList)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Trying to execute this code, I get an empty list in AController (because A is abstract).

If I remove "abstract" for class A, then I get an item in aList, the type is A, not B as I would expect.

From what I googled, I thought, `TypeNameHandling.Auto` should be the solution as

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //...

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto;
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work for me.

However, as a test, I do see `TypeNameHandling.Auto` working if I use JsonConverter directly:

```
var aList = List<A> { new B() };
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aList, Formatting.Indented, settings);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<A>>(str, settings);
```

In this case, I do get a list of B (instead of A) in obj.

**So, why it doesn't work for my WebApi?**

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167895/json-net-typenamehandling-auto-and-asp-web-api-controller-gives-unexpected-behav), which is more than two years old, saying "Web API does not use this overload" of `public void Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, object value, Type objectType);`. I can't believe it's still true after two years. Anyway, in the accepted answer of that post, Kiran provided a custom json formatter, which should fix this problem. However, when I try to plug it into my `WebApiConfig`, it doesn't work for me. In fact, the overridden `WriteToStreamAsync` doesn't get called at all - really strange.

Here is Kiran's code:

```
public class CustomJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        try
        {
            Encoding effectiveEncoding = SelectCharacterEncoding(content == null ? null : content.Headers);

            if (!UseDataContractJsonSerializer)
            {
                using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(writeStream, effectiveEncoding)) { CloseOutput = false })
                {
                    if (Indent)
                    {
                        jsonTextWriter.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
                    }

                    JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(this.SerializerSettings);
                    jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, value, type); //NOTE: passing in 'type' here
                    jsonTextWriter.Flush();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, writeStream, content, transportContext);
            }

            return TaskHelpers.Completed();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return TaskHelpers.FromError(e);
        }
    }
}

internal class TaskHelpers
{
    private static readonly Task _defaultCompleted = FromResult<AsyncVoid>(default(AsyncVoid));

    /// <summary>
    /// Used as the T in a "conversion" of a Task into a Task{T}
    /// </summary>
    private struct AsyncVoid
    {
    }

    internal static Task<TResult> FromResult<TResult>(TResult result)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        tcs.SetResult(result);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an error task. The task is Completed, IsCanceled = False, IsFaulted = True
    /// </summary>
    internal static Task FromError(Exception exception)
    {
        return FromError<AsyncVoid>(exception);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an error task of the given type. The task is Completed, IsCanceled = False, IsFaulted = True
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    internal static Task<TResult> FromError<TResult>(Exception exception)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        tcs.SetException(exception);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a completed task that has no result. 
    /// </summary>        
    internal static Task Completed()
    {
        return _defaultCompleted;
    }
}
```

Here is my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.formatters.clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new CustomJsonFormatter() { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto } });
    }
}
```

Anybody has a clue?

**UPDATE and SOLUTION:**

Okay, after some struggle, I figured it out myself. The problem is in client request using `clien.PostAsJsonAsync`. I have to use another function `PostAsync` with formatter parameter to add `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, as follows.

```
var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto } };
var response = await client.PostAsync("api/a", aList, formatter);
```

With this and `TypeNameHandling.Auto` in `WebApiConfig.cs` together, derived classes are correctly deserialized and serialized.